# Can I safely drill a four inch hole in a brick load bearing wall?

Tags: drill, exhaust-fan, masonry

I need to drill a four inch hole in a brick load bearing external wall for a kitchen fan. Is there much risk of affecting the structural integrity of the building?

It is a two storey building and the bathroom is on the floor above. Not sure of the wall thickness yet.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you (e.g. wall dimension? what's above?). Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Much less risk than if you were cutting out a square.